# jquery to create a pop up using document .createElement

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to create a pop up using jquery.(with text box and two buttons)

how to create a textbox and button using document.createElement and read the value from that textbox by clicking on that button.
which jquery library I should import

Answer (score 1):

First of all, have you tried google? There are tons of options. I usually use [Dialog](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog), because it's awesome and easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out the [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<p><a href="http://www.google.com" title="google.com" id="popOpen">open Google in a popup window</a></p> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$('#popOpen').popupWindow({ 
height:300px, 
width:300px, 
top:0px, 
left:0px 
}); 
</script>
```

this is from http://swip.codylindley.com/popupWindowDemo.html

Andy

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you need to use document.createElement if you use the jQuery UI library. You need to go to http://jqueryui.com/download and create your download making sure dialog is checked in widgets.

You can create a div element on your page that contains your text box and two buttons. set the style to display:none so its hidden to start with.

e.g.  .... code for your text box and 2 buttons

In your script file,

1. You can attach the dialog to this div using its id, something like $('#dialog').dialog() ... (look at options for dialog)
2. You can attach something for the click event of the button to read the value of the textbox